# How to get the stream from StreamSocket

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, streamwriter, .net-4.5

I am developing Metro Client- Server application and in the client I use StreamSocket to connect to the listening server. Then I try to use a StreamWriter to send data to the Server. The problem is that when I am creating the new StreamWriter object I need to give him a stream argument. In my case I need to give him the Stream from the StreamSocket. Here is what I am talking about:

> ```
>    private StreamWriter swSender;
>
>
>    private StreamSocket tcpServer;
> ```

When attempting to send data:

> ```
>    swSender = new StreamWriter(????);
>    swSender.WriteLine(mytext);
>    swSender.Flush();
> ```

???? must be the Stream from tcpServer, but there is not a GetStream() method like in TcpClient() class from the older framework. Any workarounds? Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistake he have **InputStream** and **OutputStream**

and then

```
async private void WaitForData(StreamSocket socket)
{
 var dr = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
 //dr.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
 var stringHeader = await dr.LoadAsync(4);
 if (stringHeader == 0)
 {
    // disconnected
    return;
 }

 int strLength = dr.ReadInt32();
 uint numStrBytes = await dr.LoadAsync((uint)strLength);
 string msg = dr.ReadString(numStrBytes);
 WaitForData(socket);
}
```

**EDIT**

So you need something like this

```
IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(text,   BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
tcpServer.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in your code you are waiting for response from the server and then the client gets a msg from the server. My question is more related to the case where the Client sends information to the server. That's why I am trying to use StreamWriter.

Comment: dr.ReadInt32() returns a huge number and ends up in OutOfMemoryException

Comment: @EfEs what did you try to do?

Comment: Where did you get 'OutOfMemoryException'? in 'LoadAsync'? why you didnt use 'while'?

Comment: No, in string msg = dr.ReadString(numStrBytes), the number of bytes to read were too high, like 80 million.

Comment: My solution was 

reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                        await reader.LoadAsync(BUFFER_LENGTH);
                        string msg = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

Comment: @EfEs So its crash your memory, not program. By the way my second comment to you is the same thing like your solution. Please remove downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (to dispose properly)

[Starting streamreader and writer for tcpclient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZKsD.jpg)